# how to add search in select option when data fetching from ajax call

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhWnx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7gvk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkKno.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxL50.png)

search bar is added but data not fetching in selectize jquery
and at the normal side are working fetch data option tag but after adding search bar in drop down it can not working so please help

Comment: Please transfer the image texts into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple version of your task. So may be it will helpful for you:

```js
let url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=1';
let isOpen = false;
const select = document.querySelector('#characters');

const getCharacters = (isFirstRun) => {
  if (!isFirstRun) {
    isOpen = !isOpen;

    if (isOpen) return;
  }


  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(charactersData => {
      url = charactersData.info.next;
      select.innerHTML = '';
      return charactersData.results.map(charactersData => charactersData.name);
    })
    .then(charactersNames => charactersNames.forEach(characterName => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.innerText = characterName;
      select.appendChild(option);
    }))
    .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
}

getCharacters(true);
```

```html
<select id="characters" onclick='getCharacters()'></select>
```

Comment: great brother thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input with datalist.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist